# Material Preview dosen't show textures but Render Preview does

Tags: texturing, materials

I don't know which button I clicked but the **Material Preview** is of the model is completely black, the funny thing is that when switching to **Rendered Preview** everything is how it's should...
EDIT: I checked the normals and everything is fine in that area

[image]

[image: matpreview]

[image: renderedpreview]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I've updated the question, hope it helps...

Comment: Hello :). Eevee preview issues are often caused by old graphics card drivers or incompatible hardware.

Comment: @JachymMichal my laptop is 100% fine. I've tested this with another project and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by **resetting the the view-port**. in order to do that I took the other side of the screen and dragged it over the view-port that had issues. *I later realized that the changes apply in the "Layout" workspace and all the other workplaces* that's why i got the idea to reset the workspace

Answer (score 0):

you have not packed materials that you are using for your project please pack those files in blend file by clicking on file-> external data -> pack all into blends
then save your file and upload it so i can maybe help you

Comment: sorry for that I've updated the question